# viewing pdf file created from a TEX file with acrobat reader

Tags: errors, pdf, adobe

I am using Texshop on my MacBook. I downloaded following files.

http://www.math.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/puthesis.cls
http://www.math.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/puthesis.sample.tex

When I open the puthesis.sample.pdf file with the Adobe Reader DC, which is created from the above TEX file, the following error appears on the screen.

An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem.

Could anyone help me to to get rid of this error? Thanks.

Comment: @Georg: The poster has given a MWE, or at least a WE — they’ve linked to the complete file they’re compiling, which is fairly minimal already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error seems due to

```
% the next two lines are needed to make packages using xcolor happy
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\def\current@color{ Black}
```

If I comment out the third line, the error doesn't appear.

Actually, I'd remove also `\RequirePackage{xcolor}` which is not used by the class and would create problems if a user loads a package that needs `xcolor` with some option.

Comment: Is that really `{ Black}` and not `{Black}`?

Comment: @MartinSchröder It doesn't matter: either is wrong. It's really `{ Black}` in the class file.