# Adobe unable to display images in pdf from texshop

Tags: graphics, adobe

I'm quite frustrated trying to submit a paper for review. I am getting an error message from Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (Software says it's up to date).

I am on a Mac 10.15.2 I am using Texshop 4.44 when I create my document using pdftex, it displays  beautifully using Mac preview or Chrome pdf viewer. When I open with Adobe I see "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem." without any indication of what is causing the error.

I am unsure of even where to start with troubleshooting and I'm running into some real world deadlines which are raising the stakes pretty high for me.

If you can help, I would appreciate it.
David
PS I tried the solution mentioned here

[viewing pdf file created from a TEX file with acrobat reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371918/viewing-pdf-file-created-from-a-tex-file-with-acrobat-reader)

That didn't fix the error.

My tex file is 700 lines with 20 images, I can post it if that would help. I'm using the journal's style file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: most probable cause is an issue in one of the included images, you should be able to use the usual divide and conquer, take a copy of your document, delete the second half, if that document works, delete the first half instead and try the second half. repeat until you get a small enough example to post here

Comment: What are the figures? See if Adobe is able to show embedded images of the format used (a small test file that just includes each image in turn should work for this). Any error messages? Do other viewers work? Does any of the LaTeX tools complain when building the PDF?